# How to import from FBA (Claim-based) to Active Directory (AD)?

Tags: 2010, forms-authentication, active-directory

I am on FBA (Claim-based). I need to shift to Active Directory. Is it possible to do it? The reason is that I am missing out on many features which are unavailable on FBA.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, changing the web app should be straight forward (hit the authentication method in central method and change it accordingly, if you need more info let me know)

You can easily just add the AD users into SharePoint, but I think you want their old FBA accounts and permissions to copy into their AD accounts.

Check out this script which will loop through your users and migrate them all
http://blog.sharepoint-voodoo.net/?p=68

HTH

Comment: Thx. Just a question! Will it migrate the groups with permissions and all?

Comment: it should carry over all existing permissions for users/groups, so you should be golden

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is to import all your FBA users to active directory. There are many solutions how to do this. You only need to be an active directory admin - to have permissions to add new users.